# Thread-safety of Singleton-Scoped Spring Beans in Context per Thread Environment

Tags: spring, multithreading, scope, thread-safety

I deal with a framework "X" which starts multiple threads and from each of them calls methods from a self-written JAR library. I wanted to get benefits from both of frameworks "X" and Spring, so i've designed the method which is being called from "X" in a way that it initializes Spring Context. In such way I have a Spring Context in each Thread. I can't show the code, so that's the brief description of the case. Everything is fine, just I'm just wondered about some circumstances:

1. Does that situation mean that every singleton scoped bean is becoming automatically Thread-safe (framework X handles threads itself) so I don't have to bother about ThreadLocals, local variables and can I do everything without synchronization with instance variables.
2. Do class variables still shared among all threads/spring context or bean class variables in this case become local to context?
   I have some other question if you don't mind I'll edit this question later yet. And maybe I'll write some resume of conclusions if get answers here.
   Thank You all in advance.

Comment: Don't create a context per thread. It basically means you are loading your full application for each thread. Load it once, make sure your singletons are thread safe (don't keep state) and use a single instance.

Comment: Ty I would like to, that's a hypothetic alternative way, but it's a way of samurai, which "needs" extra time to work on it and as I said I can't refuse from using framework which "borns" and more that framework may run on different hosts in parallel, born threads and call, my library, so the behavior becomes more unpredictable for me in a way you said. I guess MAKING context a "entry-point" class variable will give me a context on each host. But there are some other boilerplates in my case... I'll mark your question as answer, though that way adds me a headache and will take more time... TY

Comment: Also, as my library doesn't have a classic entry point and every thread born by framework X calls 3 life cycle methods from jar library: init(), action(), end() I'll have to make a separate singleton class for spring context I guess

Comment: Why even depend on Spring if you are writing a library? Use regular java and leave spring out-of-the-mix. Although using spring might make it easier for you, as a library maintainer, it doesn't for the sake of the people using your library (especially if they aren't and maybe even more if they are using Spring).

Comment: It's not a library in a common term, I mean it's not a runnable jar, it's a performance testing "library" :) So I need it ready asap and it won't leave the walls). Nevertheless I'm honoring all other best practices, except the one you mentioned coz of the described situation). Anyway, I guess, questions I asked are legal, regardless of purposes I use my code. Coz such circumstances can happen not only in my particular case.